# Project of the license car plate (Pascal)

Tags: pascal

I am studying Pascal and have a problem.

My code needs to make combinations of four numbers, from left to right but I want to prevent those combinations from repeating the same thing being the numbers in positions, but worth the same thing from right to left.

Does anyone have any idea how to do that?

```
program mistureba;
type 
  placa = array [1..4] of integer;
var 
  a4num : array [1..24] of placa; // a4num : array [1..24,1..4] of integer
  linha : integer;
const 
  MAXDIG = 4;

  procedure mistura(input : placa; index : integer);
    // input tem a série de digitos da placa
    // index indica a posição que inicia o arranjo
  var 
    output : placa;
    p, i : integer;
  begin
    if index = MAXDIG then
    begin // mostra / insere a sequencia que está em input
      //for i := 1 to MAXDIG do
      //write(input);
      //writeln;
      a4num[linha] := input;
      linha := linha + 1;
    end
    else
    begin
      output := input;
      for p := index to MAXDIG do
      begin
        output[index] := input[p];
        for i := index to p - 1 do
          output[i + 1] := input;
        for i := p + 1 to MAXDIG do
          output := input;
        mistura(output,index + 1);
      end;
    end;
  end;

var 
  //a4num : placa;
  p, i : integer;
begin
  linha := 1;
  for i := 1 to MAXDIG do
    readln(a4num[linha, i]);
  mistura(a4num[linha], 1);
  // vou mostrar o conteúdo do meu conjunto de placas
  for linha := 1 to 24 do
    if [i, 1] = [i, 4] then
    begin
      for i := 1 to MAXDIG do
        write(a4num[linha, i]);
      writeln;
    end
    else
    begin
      writeln('0');
    end;
  if [i,2] = [i,3] then
  begin
    for i := 1 to MAXDIG do
      write(a4num[linha, i]);
    writeln;
  end
  else
  begin
    writeln('0');
  end;
end.
```

Comment: Can you clarify the question? If the four numbers are 1,2,2,3, can 1223 appear twice (the two 2-s permuted, but the results look identical)? If 1232 is a valid combination and 2321 is another (but being the same right to left, i.e. a mirrored string), then which one should be seen in the output?

Comment: In case I want to prevent a mirrored chain from appearing again in the code.

Answer (score 1):

It was still not very clear what you wanted, so here are four solutions. You can choose the one you like:

```
program license;

uses
  classes;

type
  tIntegers = array of integer;

procedure BuildPermutation(aInput : string; aUsedCharacters : tIntegers; aBuild : string; var aOutput : tStringList);
  var
    i, j : integer;
    Used : boolean;
  begin
  for i := 1 to length(aInput) do
    begin
    Used := false;
    for j := 0 to length(aBuild) -1 do
      if aUsedCharacters[j] = i then
        begin
        Used := true;
        break;
        end;
    if not Used then
      begin
      aUsedCharacters[length(aBuild)] := i;
      aBuild := aBuild + aInput[i];
      if length(aBuild) = length(aInput) then
        aOutput.Add(aBuild)
      else
        BuildPermutation(aInput, aUsedCharacters, aBuild, aOutput);
      SetLength(aBuild, length(aBuild) - 1);
      end;
    end;
  end;

function AllPermutations(aInput : string) : tStringList;
  var
    UsedCharacters : tIntegers = nil;
    i : integer;
  begin
  result := tStringList.Create;
  SetLength(UsedCharacters, length(aInput));
  for i := 0 to length(UsedCharacters) - 1 do
    UsedCharacters[i] := 0;
  BuildPermutation(aInput, UsedCharacters, '', result);
  end;

function WithoutDuplicatesSorted(aInput : tStringList) : tStringList;
  // very easy using a built in feature of tStringList
  var
    OnePlate : string;
  begin
  result := tStringList.Create;
  result.Sorted := true;
  result.Duplicates := dupIgnore;
  for OnePlate in aInput do
    result.Add(OnePlate);
  end;

function WithoutDuplicatesUnsorted(aInput : tStringList) : tStringList;
  var
    OnePlate : string;
  begin
  result := tStringList.Create;
  for OnePlate in aInput do
    if result.IndexOf(OnePlate) = -1 then
      result.Add(OnePlate);
  end;

function WithoutMirrors(aInput : tStringList) : tStringList;
  var
    OnePlate : string;
    Mirror : string;
    i : integer;
  begin
  result := tStringList.Create;
  for OnePlate in aInput do
    begin
    Mirror := '';
    for i := 1 to length(OnePlate) do
      Mirror := OnePlate[i] + Mirror;
    if result.IndexOf(Mirror) = -1 then
      result.Add(OnePlate);
    end;
  end;

function WithoutMirrorsAndDuplicates(aInput : tStringList) : tStringList;
  var
    OnePlate : string;
    Mirror : string;
    i : integer;
  begin
  result := tStringList.Create;
  for OnePlate in aInput do
    if result.IndexOf(OnePlate) = -1 then
      begin
      Mirror := '';
      for i := 1 to length(OnePlate) do
        Mirror := OnePlate[i] + Mirror;
      if result.IndexOf(Mirror) = -1 then
        result.Add(OnePlate);
      end;
  end;

procedure PrintResult(aTitle : string; aInput : tStringList);
  var
    OnePlate : string;
  begin
  writeln(aTitle);
  for OnePlate in aInput do
    writeln(OnePlate);
  end;

procedure Solve;
  var
    Input : string = '';
    Intermediate : tStringList = nil;
    FinalResult : tStringList = nil;
  begin
  // get one version of the license plate
  // please note that it allows non-numeric characters
  // if you want, you can insert a filtering, or any other mechanism to ensure only numeric license plates
  writeln('Input one version of the license plate:');
  readln(Input);
  // make all possible permutations and print them
  Intermediate := AllPermutations(Input);
  PrintResult('All permutations', Intermediate);
  // option 1 - filter identical ones (and also sorting them to make it easy)
  FinalResult := WithoutDuplicatesSorted(Intermediate);
  PrintResult('Without duplicates sorted', FinalResult);
  FinalResult.Free;
  // option 2 - filter identical ones (without sorting them, i.e. more complicated)
  FinalResult := WithoutDuplicatesUnsorted(Intermediate);
  PrintResult('Without duplicates unsorted', FinalResult);
  FinalResult.Free;
  // option 3 - filter mirrors (be careful, it is not defined which one of 123 and 321 will be shown!!!)
  FinalResult := WithoutMirrors(Intermediate);
  PrintResult('Without mirrors', FinalResult);
  FinalResult.Free;
  // option 3 - filter mirrors and duplicates
  FinalResult := WithoutMirrorsAndDuplicates(Intermediate);
  PrintResult('Without mirrors and duplicates', FinalResult);
  FinalResult.Free;
  Intermediate.Free;
  end;

begin
Solve;
end.
```

Comment: Thanks for your code, I’m trying to apply it here in mine but I will give a study, I’ll try to record a video to explain and you understand, I don’t speak English very well so I’ll try to pronounce it as best I can.